# How to get the data-column-index in DataTables?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I already tried, `data('columnIndex')` but it gives me undefine.

I need to get the value of data-column-index for my custom reOrder function.

```
$('#columnAge').data('column-index') // undefined
$('#columnAge').data('columnIndex') // get the value of data-index instead
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please, can you post some code and and example of what you want exactly?

Comment: updated above, I just want to get the value of attr `data-column-index` in DataTables.

Answer (score 1):

Try next code:

```
$(#columnAge).attr("data-column-index")
```

I hope that work. It worked fine for my case.